# How to select (count + group by) and with join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the database that I have but I get stuck when I try to select to show `count` based by one of the columns in a table group by `id` in one of the column.

Here is the query that I have tried:

```
SELECT * , SELECT COUNT((DISTINCT daftar.id_daftar) group by daftar.id_kelas) AS Count
                            FROM kelas
                            INNER JOIN matkul
                            ON kelas.id_matkul = matkul.id_matkul
                            INNER JOIN proker
                            ON kelas.id_proker = proker.id_proker order by nama_matkul
```

daftar table

```
+-----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| id_daftar | npm    | id_kelas | tgldaftar           |
+-----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
|        26 | admin3 |        0 | 2019-06-09 13:04:58 |
|        27 | admin3 |        0 | 2019-06-09 13:07:02 |
|        28 | admin3 |        0 | 2019-06-09 13:07:41 |
|        29 | admin3 |        0 | 2019-06-09 13:08:17 |
|        30 | admin3 |        7 | 2019-06-09 14:00:54 |
|        31 | admin3 |        6 | 2019-06-09 15:34:00 |
+-----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

table kelas

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| id_kelas | id_proker | id_matkul | nama_kelas | tgl        | jam   | ruangan | status | buka_tgl   | buka_jam | keterangan | kapasitas |
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+
|        0 |         2 |         1 | nini       | 2019-06-23 | 17.00 | -       | 3      | 2019-06-23 | 20.00    | Baus       | 3         |
|        6 |         2 |         3 | B          | 2019-06-22 | 20.00 | bb      | 2      | 2019-06-27 | 12.00    | kk         | 30        |
|        7 |         1 |         1 | Aduh       | 2019-06-14 | 23.00 | nddm    | 2      | 2019-06-29 | 20.00    | oke        | 1         |
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

table matkul

```
+-----------+------------------+
| id_matkul | nama_matkul      |
+-----------+------------------+
|         1 | akuntansi biayaz |
|         3 | ewean            |
|         5 | ewe              |
|         6 | tes              |
|         7 | Tesd             |
+-----------+------------------+
```

table proker

```
+-----------+---------------------------+
| id_proker | nama_proker               |
+-----------+---------------------------+
|         1 | Bebelac                   |
|         2 | Mentoring Accounting Club |
+-----------+---------------------------+
```

Here is the expected result example:

[image: result photo]

Anyone can help my case?
Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need   the distinct count for each daftar.id_kelas

```
SELECT  daftar.id_kelas COUNT(DISTINCT daftar.id_daftar) AS Count
FROM kelas
INNER JOIN matkul  ON kelas.id_matkul = matkul.id_matkul
INNER JOIN proker  ON kelas.id_proker = proker.id_proker 
group by daftar.id_kelas
```

if you want the rows and the count  then you could use an inner  join the subquery for count

```
select *,  t.count
from  kelas 
inner join  (
   SELECT  daftar.id_kelas, COUNT(DISTINCT daftar.id_daftar) AS Count
   FROM kelas
   INNER JOIN matkul  ON kelas.id_matkul = matkul.id_matkul
   INNER JOIN proker  ON kelas.id_proker = proker.id_proker
   group by daftar.id_kelas
) t on t.id_kelas = kelas.id_kelas
```

any way looking to your schema seems you need

```
  SELECT  daftar.id_kelas COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM daftar 
  INNER JOIN kelas on daftar.id_kelas = kelas.id_kelas 
  INNER JOIN matkul  ON kelas.id_matkul = matkul.id_matkul
  INNER JOIN proker  ON kelas.id_proker = proker.id_proker 
  group by daftar.id_kelas
```

if you want the rows and the count then you could use an inner join the subquery for count

```
  select *,  t.count
  from  daftar  
  inner join  (
     SELECT  daftar.id_kelas COUNT(*) AS Count
      FROM daftar 
      INNER JOIN kelas on daftar.id_kelas = kelas.id_kelas 
      INNER JOIN matkul  ON kelas.id_matkul = matkul.id_matkul
      INNER JOIN proker  ON kelas.id_proker = proker.id_proker 
  group by daftar.id_kelas
  ) t on t.id_kelas = daftar.id_kelas
```

Comment: i dont just wanna distinct but also select other inner join table, ive update my expected result btw.. ive an error through ur code anw

Comment: have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'group by daftar.id_kelas ) t on t.id_kelas = kelas' at line 16

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by daftar.id_kelas
) t on t.id_kelas = kelas.id_kelas LIMIT 0, 25' at line 8

Comment: i have not limit  .. in my query  .. so try update your question and show me the actual query you are really using

Comment: PS  you are also  referring to  daftar table but this in not mention in FROM and JOIN clause ..  ..check better you original query  .. are you sure this query  work .. removing the select * ??   you should add  you real tables  schema  a clear data sample an not only  a link to image for expected  result

Comment: I think the `ORDER BY` in the sub-query is misplaced @scaisEdge

Comment: `INNER JOIN proker  ON kelas.id_proker = proker.id_proker order by nama_matkul` < there's one here.. probably coming from the OP's original query @scaisEdge